# How to make nosetests use python3

Tags: python, nose

I try to use `nosetests`
    ❯ nosetests '/pathTo/test'

but it uses `python 2.7` for my tests:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

So some of them fails, because they were written in `python 3.3`.

I work it around and installed virtual environment:

```
pyvenv-3.3 py3env
```

Activated it:

```
source ~/py3env/bin/activate
```

Check python virsion in virtual environment:

```
❯ python --version                                                                                 ⏎
Python 3.3.3
(py3env)
```

Ok.
But nosetest still uses `python2.7` even in virtual environment:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

So my tests fails. 
**How to make nose use python3?**

Comment: Are you using nosetests from virtual environment?

Comment: yes. I activate virtual environment and then in the same console use nose.

Comment: I would try running manually `~/py3env/bin/nosetests-script.py` with your python interpreter and check the results.

Comment: @Oleksiy no such file or directory: `~/py3env/bin/nosetests-script.py`.  `~/py3env/bin` has the following structure:  `activate  python    python3   python3.3`

Comment: did you install nose in py3env?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `Python 3.4` and higher versions: in order to make nose use `python3` just run ...

```
python3 -m "nose"
```

... in the target directory with the tests.

The environment setups are not required.

Comment: This is convenient, have you any idea how to pass arguments e.g. `nosetests -e my-test`?

Comment: @moreginger  `python3 -m nose -e my-test`

Comment: `pip3 install nose` to make sure it's actually installed, first. In my case, this was needed, since python2 nose was installed while python3 wasn't.

Answer (score 8):

To install:

`sudo apt-get install python-nose python3-nose`

To run:

`nosetests-2.7 ; nosetests3`

This runs the test suite under both PY2 and PY3.

Comment: Can I only install the python3 version?
and then use it like:
`sudo apt install python3-nose` 
`nosetests3`

Comment: After I tested this, it's possible to only install the `python3-nose` version, run as:
`sudo apt install python3-nose` && `nosetests3`

Answer (score 2):

I found way to use nosetests with python3 without environment:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin
```

And then:

```
❯ nosetests-3.3 '/folder/with/tests'
```

`nosetests-3.3` uses `python 3`

That's it.

And if your want use command `nosetests` instead of `nosetests-3.3`, add in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
nosetests()
{
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/nosetests-3.3 $1
}
```

Now you can use:

```
nosetests '/folder/with/tests'
```

from any directory. It uses `python3`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can link nosetests-3.3:
```ln /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/nosetests-(version-number) /usr/local/bin/nosetests3```

Comment: Better to use `"$@"` instead of `$1`. That way you pass _all_ arguments through, quoting is preserved, globbing is suppressed when quoting indicates that it should be, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a virtualenv issue as much as a linux issue.

This means that when you use the command `nosetests` from the terminal, linux looks within it's available paths (`/bin`, `/sbin`, or whatever it is by you) for such an executable file.

Your global python 2 `nosetests` is found first and executed.

Your virtualenv python3 `nosetests` is later in the available path list and therefore never reached.

I would suggest to only install nose or any other python command per virtual environment.