# How do i make pyinvoke use python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyinvoke

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779289/how-to-make-nosetests-use-python3) but not quite the same.

I have python2.7 and python3.5 installed. I can run scripts using either of them from the command line. My current default "python" is python2.

I have a python3 script using pyinvoke that i need to run, which is typically run using the command `invoke <task>` from the command line. Even when i set up a virtual environment that uses python3, `invoke` still uses python2.

I assume there is something i am missing about virtual environments?

The only work-around i have for this right now is to only install pyinvoke for python3. Then it will run under python3.

Does someone know how to set this up to work with virtual environments?

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess you have installed [invoke](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke) globally, outside of all virtualenvs.

If so, a fix would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Remove global invoke, at a fresh terminal or after deactivate
$ pip uninstall invoke
```

To test it, add to Invoke's `tasks.py` file:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

Then at a Terminal check we get Python 3.x:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
$ mkvirtualenv myproject_py3 --python=$(which python3)
(myproject_py3)$ pip install invoke
(myproject_py3)$ invoke --list
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
No tasks found in collection 'tasks'!
```

Answer (score 0):

As [pzrq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1101109/pzrq) mentioned, the issue is you have invoke installed globally.

This isn't a virtualenv issue as much as a linux issue.

This means that when you use the command `invoke` from the terminal, linux looks within it's available paths (`/bin`, `/sbin`, or whatever it is by you) for such an executable file.

Your global python 2 `invoke` is found first and executed.

Your virtualenv python3 `invoke` is later in the available path list and therefore never reached.

I would suggest to only install invoke per virtual environment.